# How to accomplish this RecyclerView with horizontal scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create a RecyclerView with two CardViews visible inside of it that can scroll horizontally. Similar to the picture below. [image]

Setting the LayoutManager to this code creates the desired format but it is scrolling vertically.

```
recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(Context, 2, GridLayoutManager.Vertical, false));
```

[image]

Setting the LayoutManager to this code creates an incorrect format but it is scrolling horizontally.

```
recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(Context, 2, GridLayoutManager.Horizontal, false));
```

[image]

My question is how do I create a format of two CardViews that are side by side and can scroll horizontally?

Here is the CardView XML just in case it is needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#FF0000">
  </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a LinearLayoutManager instead of a GridLayoutManager?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a LinearLayoutManager with horizontal orientation:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

If you want to show 2 cards at the same time, set their width to half of the screen size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have thought about using a LinearLayoutManager but the issue with that is how do you equalize the widths of the two CardViews inside of it so that they are the same in the parent. Also what would happen if I wanted to display three CardViews now? It wouldn't be as simple as using the GridLayoutManager and changing the number of columns.

Comment: You could do `cardWidth = screenSize / COLUMNS_NUMBER`, and just change the last constant if you want to add more columns. `GridLayoutManager` works if you want to make a grid with more than 1 row and column, not your case.

Comment: Or you can try using `android:weight` in your CardViews, but I don't know if it works

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. Where should I set the cardWidth? Inside the adapter in the onCreateViewHolder method does not allow the width of the CardView to be changed as it is readonly. This also applies to onBindViewHolder method.